# Why Datatable properties are lost when a table is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, datatables

I have a problem I can not solve the .

I have a screen where I have a textarea in which a code is pasted from Excel and when you click on the button " Generate table " an HTML table with the same structure type is generated. Until I get there all right, but now I am trying to create a table of Datatable now type but at the moment of creating properties as the " filter" or "the total records " are lost. In fact it does not scroll within the table , in a nutshell is not created with the properties .

I leave my code segment and I hope you can help me .

//HTML table code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tableMovimientos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2/</th>
                <th>Column 3/</th>
                <th>Column 4/</th>
                <th>Column 5/</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

//HTML div for table generate code

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <p>Paste you excel data:</p>
    <textarea name="excel_data" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="btn-generateTable" type="button" class="btn btn-info"> Generate table <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
    <br>
    <div id="excel_table">
    </div>
</div>
```

//Jquery button "Generate table" Code

```
$("#btn-generateTabla").click(function() {
    var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
    console.log(data);
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    var table = $('<table />');

    var aux = "";
    for (var y in rows) {
        var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
        var row = $('<tr />');
        aux += "'<tr>\n'";
        for (var x in cells) {
            row.append('<td>' + cells[x] + '</td>');
            aux += '<td>' + cells[x] + '</td> \n';
        }
        aux += "</tr> \n"
            //alert(y + " " + rows)
    }
    table.append(row);

    //alert(aux)

    // Insert into DOM
    $('#tableMovimientos tbody').html(aux);
});
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: adding rows to an initialised datatable isn't just a case of creating an html string and appending it, you have to use the internal api for that which depends on which version of the plugin you are using. You could do the html string concatenation and append it to the table and *then* initialise datatables and you will probably fare a lot better if that's possible for you, otherwise, you'll need to have a read of the docs.